# A little confusion around generics

Tags: java, generics

I started reading some article about generics in Java and one thing confused me:

```
public static <t> T getFirst(List<T> list)
```

"This method will accept a reference to a List and will return an object of type T."

cool, but what does `<t>` do (the lower case one, after static)? I tried and failed to understand it...

Comment: It should be `<T>` rather than `<t>`

Comment: typo in the article then, I thought it smelled fishy...

Comment: @Kugathasan Abimaran Please do not alter the case of `t` - it is exactly that what the question is about

Comment: @Kobi, My correction is correct, OP did a type there.

Comment: @Andreas : My correction is correct, OP did a type there.

Comment: I just copied it from the article, and I didn't understand why lower case? That's the whole point

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran No. Read the question: `what does <t> do (the lower case one, after static)`. How would anyone be able to correspond that to the code if you modify it? **Never** modify code in a question other than code formatting and indentation, since it might change the whole synopsis of the question

Comment: @Andreas : Check OP's first comment

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Right, **typo in the article** OP was reading, **not** in the question

Comment: @Andreas : It's OK, I want to make sense of that question, no problem at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should rather be :

```
public static <T> T getFirst(List<T> list)
```

- **So, what does the `<T>` mean ?**

  It means that there is a type called `<T>` for the scope of this method. And the method will return an instance of that type `T`, also.
- **How to use it ?**

  If you pass a `List<String>` the method should return the first `String` in the list.

  If you pass a `List<Integer>` the method should return the first `Integer` in the list.
- **What's the point of supporting such methods ?**

  - You don't have to **overload** methods with different signatures, according to the type of the objects in the `List` and
  - You don't have to worry that the method will return other type than the type of the objects in the list, which will relief you from the burden of possible casting, for example.

Comment: Not sure noe which <T> are you talking about. I understand the second one (List<T> list) but I just wasn't sure why exactly we need <T> T rather than just T. But I guess I start getting an idea.

Comment: If you have a parameter `List<T> list` you should have somewhere defined that there is a generic type `<T>` (either for the class or only of the method).

Comment: Ok, so if class declaration would look like: public class Foo<T> {...}, then the method inside it could just be: public static T getFirst(List<T> list)?

Comment: Exactly. You can try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is more understandable like this:

```
public static <T> T getFirst(T something)
```

In short  means that the type **T** will be a parameter given later when you call the method:

```
String text = "text";
getfirst(text);
```

Now the compiler will know that all the **T** means `String` here.